# Comparison of 'comparison' sorts

Tags: algorithm, sorting, comparison

I read the following statement while comparing heap sort and merge sort:

Merge sort can be adapted to operate on linked lists with O(1) extra space. Heap sort can be adapted to operate on doubly linked lists with only O(1) extra space overhead.

Would appreciate help in explaining this (am not computer science educated) — though I understand the how the above sorts work at an elementary level.

Comment: You need to be more specific about which of aspect you do not understand - or wait for someone who has a lot patience to type the explanation of the algorithms all out.

Comment: I am trying to understand the relevance of the 'extra' word here.I really do not need to understand the algorithms.Rather what causes this 'extra' space overhead for a linked list.

Comment: At very least you must have some variables to keep track of where you are, so there must be an overhead somewhere. Could you still try to be a bit more specific?

Comment: OK.I guess I need to clarify - i seek to understand how the space and time notations change (if at all),when a merge and a heap sort tackle a linkedlist vs an unsorted array.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_notation). It is used to describe the complexity (time/memory usage) of an algorithm (check the link for more details). What is meant here is that the algorithms you read about can be extended to work in the mentioned cases and the change needed to be made would result in a constant-more space required. That is the extra space would not depend on the size of the structure. It would be constant - for example one variable more.

**EDIT:**

Some of the most used notations:

- O(1) - constant - the time or memory used does not depend on the size of the structure the algorithm works on
- O(n) - linear - depends on the size of the structure - the bigger the structure - the more time/memory is required
- O(logn) - [logarithmic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_time#Logarithmic_time)
  ...

For more details check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)